# React-admin: ReferenceInput doesn't show loading <LinearProgress> while loading possible options

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have simple react-admin edit form with ReferenceInput. The problem is that ReferenceInput never show progress bar, so it might be confusing for users to see no options while it's loading.

I manually set delay 2 seconds on API calls but ReferenceInput never show loading state.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ReferenceInput, ReferenceArrayInput, required, SelectArrayInput, SelectInput, SimpleForm, TextInput } from 'react-admin';

const ModelForm = props => (
    <SimpleForm {...props}>
        <TextInput source="name" validate={[required()]} />
        <ReferenceInput reference="goods_types" source="goodsType" validate={[required()]}>
            <SelectInput optionText="name" />
        </ReferenceInput>
        <ReferenceInput reference="manufacturers" source="manufacturer" validate={[required()]}>
            <SelectInput optionText="name" />
        </ReferenceInput>
        <ReferenceArrayInput reference="manufacturers" source="manufacturer" format={v => [v]} validate={[required()]}>
            <SelectArrayInput optionText="name" />
        </ReferenceArrayInput>
    </SimpleForm>
);

export default ModelForm;
```

Just for test I added ReferenceArrayInput component and it **does show** loading progress bar.
Is it bug in react-admin? Or am I missing something?

**React-admin: 3.11.1**

Comment: This is a bug in react-admin, it should be fixed in the next minor release, see https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/5731

Comment: @FrançoisZaninotto it fixed an issue, but now it's not possible to use ReferenceInput with AutocompleteInput since it'll reset user input each time user start typing.

Answer (score 0):

React Admin introduced a timeout with default value of 1000. The loading component only appear after this time. You can override this value by passing a prop to the component.

ref: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/ea1f85c73f5be8f12544a0fccf32e4f6bd7452be/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/layout/LinearProgress.tsx